# Prolog: consider clauses from a dynamic module when calling a predicate

Tags: module, prolog, swi-prolog

In the [SWI Prolog manual](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dynamic-modules), I found the following remark:

> For example, assume an application that can reason about multiple worlds. It is attractive to store the data of a particular world in a module, so we extract information from a world simply by invoking goals in this world.

This is actually a very good description of what I'm trying to achieve. However I ran into a problem. While I do want to model many different worlds, there are also things that I want to share across all of them. So my idea is to have an `allworlds` module for things that are true in every world, and one module for every world that I want to reason about, and the latter imports from the former. So I'd do something like this in the REPL:

```
allworlds:asserta(grandparent(X, Z) :- (parent(X, Y), parent(Y, Z))).
allworlds:dynamic(parent/2).
add_import_module(greece, allworlds, start).
greece:asserta(parent(kronos, zeus)).
greece:asserta(parent(zeus, ares)).
```

Now I'd like to query `greece:grandparent(kronos, X)` and get `X = ares`, but all I get is `false`. When `allworlds:grandparent` calls `parent`, it doesn't call `greece:parent` like I want it to, but `allworlds:parent`. My research seems to indicate that I need to make the `grandparent` predicate module-transparent. But calling `allworlds:module_transparent(grandparent/2).` didn't fix the issue, and it's also deprecated. This is where I'm stuck. How can I get this working? Is [`meta_predicate/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=meta_predicate/1) part of the solution? Unfortunately I can't make heads or tails of its documentation.

Comment: This seems to be similar to what I tried to do some time ago. Have a look: [A cross-module “interface” call in SWI-Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66146716/a-cross-module-interface-call-in-swi-prolog)

Comment: https://logtalk.org/2019/11/13/many-worlds-design-pattern.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately solved this by passing the module around explicitly and invoking predicates in it with the `:` operator. It reminds me a bit of doing OOP in C, where you do things like `obj->vtable->method(obj, params)` (note how `obj` is mentioned twice, just like the `M` in my code below).

Similar to the Logtalk solution, I need to explicitly call into the imported module when I want to consider its clauses. As an example, I've added the fact that a father is also a parent to the `allworlds` module.

```
allworlds:assertz(grandparent(M, X, Z) :- (M:parent(M, X, Y), M:parent(M, Y, Z))).
allworlds:assertz(parent(M, X, Y) :- M:father(M, X, Y)).
add_import_module(greece, allworlds, start).
greece:assertz(parent(_, kronos, zeus)).
% need to call into allworlds explicitly
greece:assertz(parent(M, X, Y) :- allworlds:parent(M, X, Y)). 
greece:assertz(father(_, zeus, ares)).
```

After making these assertions, I can call `greece:grandparent(greece, kronos, X).` and get the expected result  `X = ares`.

Answer (score 3):

Prolog modules don't provide a good solution for the "many worlds" design pattern. Notably, making the predicates meta-predicates (or module transparent or multifile) would be a problematic hack. But this pattern is trivial with Logtalk, which is a language extends Prolog and can use most Prolog systems as a backend compiler. A minimal (but not unique) solution for your problem is:

```
:- object(allworlds).

    :- public(grandparent/2).
    grandparent(X, Z) :-
        ::parent(X, Y),
        ::parent(Y, Z).

    :- public(parent/2).

:- end_object.


:- object(greece,
    extends(allworlds)).

    parent(kronos, zeus).
    parent(zeus, ares).

:- end_object.
```

Here, we use inheritance (the individual worlds inherit the common knowledge) and messages to *self* (the `::/1` control construct) when common predicates need to access world specific predicate definitions (*self* is the object/world that received the message - `grandparent/2` in the example).

Assuming the code is saved in a `worlds.lgt` file and that you're using SWI-Prolog as the backend:

```
$ swilgt
...
?- {worlds}.
% [ /Users/pmoura/worlds.lgt loaded ]
% (0 warnings)
true.

?- greece::grandparent(kronos, X).
X = ares.
```

P.S. If running on windows, use the "Logtalk - SWI-Prolog" shortcut from the Start Menu after installing Logtalk.

Comment: Hey Paolo, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately my program isn't written in Prolog, it actually runs on the JVM. It gets a description of a world from the outside, translates that into Prolog facts, asserts those using JPL, does some queries, and then retracts them again. I'm really just using it as a logic engine. Would that still work with Logtalk?
Unfortunately the above approach doesn't mesh well with concurrency, which is why I was looking into modules to separate different worlds in the first place.

Comment: For using Logtalk + SWI-Prolog + JPL, see e.g. https://logtalk.org/using_jpl.html

Comment: Hey Paolo,
I've finally gotten around to trying the proposed solution, and I have one question about it: is it possible to add additional clauses for a predicate in a derived object that is already defined in the base object? For example, when I add `grandparent(kronos, hephaistos).` to the `greece` object above, then `greece::grandparent(kronos, ares)` no longer holds. Is it possible to fix that without an explicit supercall?

Comment: You will need a *super* call in the derived object to allow the inherited definitions to be found in addition to the local definitions. See e.g. https://logtalk.org/manuals/userman/inheritance.html#union-of-inherited-and-local-predicate-definitions